# In the table, water usage in Brazil and America "is compared" or "are compared"? Which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, coordinating-conjunctions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

*In the table, water usage in Brazil and America **is** compared.*

or

*In the table, water usage in Brazil and America **are** compared.*

Comment: Note that the precise phrasing is important here. A sentence with essentially identical meaning could have a different answer: "In the table, Brazil and America **are** compared based on water usage."

Answer (score 1):

**Is compared**. The subject is *water usage*, not America nor Brazil.

Comment: The head word of the subject NP is "usage". "Water" is a complement.

Comment: arguably it's a compound noun, _water usage_.

Comment: @OliverMason I wouldn't go along with that, Oliver. "Water usage" is a syntactic construction (complement+head). It contrasts with morphological compounds, which are composed of two bases and which are single lexemes. Compare "greenhouse" vs  "green house"

Comment: @BillJ As most things in linguistics, it's a matter of interpretation. I can see your point, though I would call it a 'modifier' (I only use 'complement' in the syntactic sense).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

> In the table, water usage in Brazil and America **is** compared

## Elaborate answer

According to [this source](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/are-subjects-joined-by-and-singular-or-plural-grammar-rules), if subjects are joined by "and", you determine the number of the verb by the following procedure:
 Split up the sentence into two and assess whether the meaning is still the same. If this is the case, the verb has to *plural*. Otherwise, it is *singular*.

For the sentence to be "**are** compared" we'd need

> In the table, water usage in Brazil is compared.

and

> In the table, warter usage in America is compared.

each to be senseful on their own, which they aren't. Therefore, we need a singular verb.

Comment: You got the right answer, but for the wrong reason. According to those rules, you would need to say *"water usage in Brazil and America are increasing"* and *"schools in Brazil and America is compared."* That's wrong.